# How to hold off certain HTTP requests at HTTP Interceptor in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, angular-http-interceptors

I have an Angular code and the story behind is as this. I have 3 HTTP calls and from one call I need a special header (X) that is required by the other two HTTP calls and I can't control the execution of these calls. So when a HTTP call that requires the X header goes before the HTTP call which gives me the X header, how can I hold off the call and let the particular HTTP call go and acquire the X header and continue the rest of the calls with the X header appended to the rest of the HTTP calls? It may seem like I'm trying to create a HTTP call queue until I get the X header and continue the rest of the calls again. Some help would be appreciated. The code is as follows.

template:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="do()"> Do </button>
```

App.ts file

```
 export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
  public do(): void {
    this.dataService.first().subscribe();
    this.dataService.second().subscribe((res) => {
      this.dataService.third().subscribe();
    });
  }
}
```

data-service.ts which has the 3 HTTP calls

```
const httpOptions1 = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'A': 'A' })
};

const httpOptions2 = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'X': 'X' })
};

const httpOptions3 = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'B': 'B' })
};

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public first(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Call One')
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}`, httpOptions1);
  }

  public second(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Call Two')
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}`, httpOptions2);
  }

  public third(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Call Three')
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}`, httpOptions3);
  }
}
```

It is the second call which has my X header and from the Interceptor what I want to do is that when the `first()` call goes off, I want to hold it add and let the `second()` call go and acquire the X header and then re-run the `first()` call from the interceptor level.

Below is the code of the Interceptor

```
private pocessed: boolean = false;
  private queue: any[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, delegate: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
        /**
         * Filter a certain http call with a certain X http header where this call provides a new header
         * to be appended to all other http calls
         */
        if (req.headers.has('X')) {
            return delegate.handle(req).do((event) => {
                if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
                    // new header data acquired; hence the boolean turned to true
                    this.pocessed = true;
                }
            });
        } else if (this.pocessed) {
            /**
             * if new header data acquired, append the new header to the rest of the calls
             */
            if (this.queue.length > 0) {
                // append header data to previous http calls
                this.queue.forEach(element => {
                    let request = new HttpRequest(element.req['method'], element.req['url'], element.req['body'], {
                        headers: element.req['headers'],
                        reportProgress: true,
                        params: element.req['params'],
                        responseType: element.req['responseType'],
                        withCredentials: element.req['withCredentials']
                    });

                    // this.fakeIntercept(request, element.next);
                });
            }
            // if new header data acquired, append the header to the rest of the calls
            req = req.clone({ setHeaders: { 'X': 'X' } });
            return delegate.handle(req).do((event) => console.log(event));
        } else {
            /**
             * these http calls need X header but the call to get the X header hasnt gone yet
             * therefor storing these calls in a queue to be used later when the header arrives
             */
            this.queue.push({req: req, next: delegate});
            return Observable.empty<any>();
        }
    }

    fakeIntercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, delegate: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
        req = req.clone({ setHeaders: { 'X': 'X' } });
        return delegate.handle(req);
    }
```

If you guys need any clarification please hit me up in the comments. If you see anything I've done wrong here please do share with me. Any improvements to the code is welcome.

Comment: Call the first one...get headers and perform other calls, why to hold the call.

Comment: @mahi I am not in a position to control how the calls go. They are popping dynamically and I have no control over them other than to put them in a cue

Comment: For the first call, you are getting response json that contains some header object which is used by other two calls. Am I correct

Comment: @mahi Its not always the first call. That's why I need to hold the other calls off. Here i've just mimicked the actual behaviour in the app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution and its pretty good for me atm. I'm using a SUbject stream to mimic the behavior of a Queue and let requests stack up Until I get the data from the X header http call. Below is the code. Hope it makes sense. Cheers!

```
public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, delegate: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            if (req.headers.has('X') && this.headerAcquired == false) {
                this.headerAcquired = true;
                const subscription = delegate.handle(req).subscribe(event => {
                    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                        this.pocessed = true;
                        this.requestSetter({key: this.pocessed});
                        this.removeRequest(req);
                        observer.next(event);
                    }
                },
                err => {
                    this.removeRequest(req);
                    observer.error(err);
                },
                () => {
                    this.removeRequest(req);
                    observer.complete();
                });
                // remove request from queue when cancelled
                return () => {
                    this.removeRequest(req);
                    subscription.unsubscribe();
                };
            } else {
                this.requests.push(req);

                this.requestGetter().subscribe(res => {
                    const i = this.requests.indexOf(req);
                    if (i >= 0) {
                        this.subjectInit = true;
                        this.requests.splice(i, 1);
                        req = req.clone({ setHeaders: { 'X': 'X' } });
                        const subscription = delegate.handle(req).subscribe(event => {
                            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                                this.pocessed = true;
                                this.request.next(true);
                                this.removeRequest(req);
                                observer.next(event);
                            }
                        },
                        err => {
                            this.removeRequest(req);
                            observer.error(err);
                        },
                        () => {
                            this.subjectInit = false;
                            this.removeRequest(req);
                            observer.complete();
                        });
                        // remove request from queue when cancelled
                        return () => {
                            this.removeRequest(req);
                            subscription.unsubscribe();
                            this.request.unsubscribe();
                        };
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Put a comment if u need more clarification on this :)